# asp.net 4 visual studio 2010 jquery master page not working

Tags: jquery, asp.net, master-pages

Update: I did try this website with Google Chrome and same result as IE

Update: I did change the Default.aspx script to

```
$("#btnSearch").click(function () {
```

and the button to

```
<asp:Button ID="btnSearch" runat="server" Text="Search"  ClientIDMode="Static" />
```

I've been using Ajax Control Toolkit for several years.  Want to play with jQuery. I can not get a simple jQuery tutorial to work.  I am learning jQuery using the tutorials:

[jquery_webforms_Using_Animations](http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/jquery_webforms_Using_Animations.ashx)

In this tutorial - I jumped down to just trying to popup a dialog box - in this case a search window.

Using Visual Studio 2010 I create a new website.  Visual Studio automatically creates a master page, default page, jquery scripts in the scripts folder, etc.

I add ScriptManager to Master Page.  I remove login stuff from Master Page - since I dont need that additional complexity for jquery tutorials.

I delete the contents that Visual Studio created in the "BodyContent" in Default.aspx.

I add the script command to load jquery to the header content of Default.aspx.  I add a short script that attaches an event handler to the button to popup the dialog box.  I threw in a couple of alerts to see what is firing.

In the content body I add a button that will popup the dialog and I add the dialog that will popup.

I compile and run the application, my Default.aspx comes up, I can click on the Search button, it does post back - but no alerts and no popup dialog.

I could not imagine a simplier example - but it does not work.  Any ideas?  Thanks.

Master Page:

```
<%@ Master Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="Site.Master.vb" Inherits="Site" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
<head runat="server">
<title></title>
<link href="~/Styles/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="HeadContent" runat="server">
</asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>
<body>
<form runat="server">
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
</asp:ScriptManager>
<div class="page">
    <div class="header">
        <div class="title">
            <h1>
                My ASP.NET Application
            </h1>
        </div>
        <div class="clear hideSkiplink">
            <asp:Menu ID="NavigationMenu" runat="server" CssClass="menu" EnableViewState="false" IncludeStyleBlock="false" Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Items>
                    <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/Default.aspx" Text="Home"/>
                    <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/About.aspx" Text="About"/>
                </Items>
            </asp:Menu>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="main">
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContent" runat="server"/>
    </div>
    <div class="clear">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="footer">

</div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the Default.aspx

```
<%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="VB" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="false"
CodeFile="Default.aspx.vb" Inherits="_Default" %>

<asp:Content ID="HeaderContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent">
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.js" type="text/javascript" />
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        alert("Setting Click event handler");
        $("<%=btnSearch.clientID%>").click(function () {
            alert("Showing dialog");
            $("#searchdialog").slideDown("slow");
        });
    });
</script>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
<asp:Button ID="btnSearch" runat="server" Text="Search" />
<div id="searchdialog" style="position: absolute; top: 65px; right: 5px; width: 200px;
    display: none;">
    <div>
        Search For Symbol</div>
    <div>
        Enter a symbol:
        <input type="text" name="txtSymbolSearch" id="txtSymbolSearch" value="" />
        <input type="button" id="btnSymbolSearch" value="Search" />
    </div>
</div>
</asp:Content
```

Comment: why do you have two search buttons? One of them is a .net control and the other is plain html

Comment: is your alert("Setting Click event handler"); firing?

Comment: neither alert shows up.  I also thought this was along the root of the problem ... but I have no idea why it would not be wiring up the event handler on the document ready?

Comment: I was googling other posts about document ready not firing and it was saying that jquery was not loading.  So I changed my line to jquery as <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-1.5.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script> and then the alerts started firing

Answer (score 3):

Missing "#" with id in jQuery:

```
$("#<%=btnSearch.clientID%>")
```

Try this:

```
 <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            alert("Setting Click event handler");
            $("#<%=btnSearch.clientID%>").click(function () {
                alert("Showing dialog");
                $("#searchdialog").slideDown("slow");
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: What's different in your example?

Comment: @jrummell  $("#<%=btnSearch.clientID%>")

Comment: You should note that in your answer.

Comment: if this doesn't work try to switch to static id mode. And instead of binding the name type the effective one. This is possible in ASP.NET 4 -> <asp:Button ClientIDMode="Static" ...

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I changed that one line of script to :: $("#<%=btnSearch.clientID%>").click(function () { :: and there was no change in functionality.

Comment: I changed the button to static as :: <asp:Button ID="btnSearch" runat="server" Text="Search"  ClientIDMode="Static" /> :: and saw no change

Comment: The ClientIDMode = static was interesting to learn since ASP.NET dynamic html it generated now has :: $("#btnSearch").click(function () { :: and the button is now defined as :: <input type="submit" name="ctl00$MainContent$btnSearch" value="Search" id="btnSearch" />
:: so it appears that ClientIdMode = "Static" is doing its job - just does not fix the problem

Comment: @KeithBaldwin can you install firebug (http://getfirebug.com/) & see if the page is throwing any JS error. Also, try using fiddler, if something is missing or not found.